# php & mysql form data

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

```js
<?php
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sudhar";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Firstname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Firstname']);
$Lastname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Lastname']);
$Username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Username']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
$Password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Password']);




$sql="insert into useraccount(Firstname,Lastname,Username,email,Password)values('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Username','$Password','$email')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
echo "data inserted"
or die(mysql_error());
}



?>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <title>ASK</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boot.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>school name</h1>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="../project/photo/l.png"  height="150px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#mynavbar">schoolName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target=_self>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="infra.html" target=_self>Infrastructure</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="stlogin.html">staff login</a></li>
            <li><a href="stdetails.html">staff details</a></li>
            <li><a href="class.html">class handling</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="signup.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="signup">
 <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="user.php">
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Firstname" class="form-control" id="fnmae" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Lastname">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Lastname" class="form-control" id="lnmae" placeholder="Enter Lastname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" id="unmae" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div></div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div></div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="Password" name="Password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div></div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><br>
    
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer nav">
  <p> Copyrights@ &copy; WWW.schools.com</p>
  </div>   
  </body>
  </html>
```

hi guys i am trying to insert my form data into mysql but when i enter the details and submit it .i am not able to get the data in database .may i know where i am wrong.thank you for your help in advance

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sudhar";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Firstname=$_POST['Firstname'];
$Lastname=$_POST['Lastname'];
$Username=$_POST['Username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];




$sql="insert into useraccount(Firstname,Lastname,Username,email,Password)values('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Username','$Password','$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql) 
echo "data inserted";
or die(mysql_error());
}



?>
```

```css
html,body
{
margin:0px; 
height:100%;
}
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
  }
 .content
 {
width:100%;
height:400px;

 }

 .signup
 {
height:500px;

 }
  .footer
  {
    position:relative;
   background-color:black;
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <title>ASK</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boot.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>school name</h1>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="../project/photo/l.png"  height="150px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#mynavbar">schoolName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target=_self>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="infra.html" target=_self>Infrastructure</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="stlogin.html">staff login</a></li>
            <li><a href="stdetails.html">staff details</a></li>
            <li><a href="class.html">class handling</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="signup.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="signup">
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="user.php">
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="Firstname" class="form-control" id="fnmae" placeholder="Enter Firstname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Lastname">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="Lastname" class="form-control" id="lnmae" placeholder="Enter Lastname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Username">Username:</label>
      <input type="Username" class="form-control" id="unmae" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div></div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div></div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div></div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><br>
    
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer nav">
  <p> Copyrights@ &copy; WWW.schools.com</p>
  </div>   
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `$sql="insert into useraccount(Firstname,Lastname,Username,email,Password) values ($Firstname,$Lastname,$Username,$Password,$email)";`

have you try like this way ?

Comment: u are mixing mysqli_* and mysql_*, add php error_reporting, u also have syntax error `$result=mysql_query($sql) ` missing semicolon

Comment: if Database username is correct than, this will work `$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

Comment: last, code open for SQL injection

Comment: add method="POST" in  <form class="form-horizontal" action="user.php">
and for every input u want to pass add <input name="firstname" ... >
<input name="username"..> and so on

Comment: There are **way too many errors** in your code and a lot of missing syntax to get your POSTs populated.

Answer (score 4):

First of you must need to use [PHP Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on development line, this will help to find errors and warnings because you have some syntax errors in your code.

```
<?php
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Than you must need to learn about the [HTML input field's types](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp), for suppose, `firstname` and `lastname` fields are text fields than you need to use something like:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname">
```

Third, very important, you are mixing the `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` extension together, you need execute your query as:

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Fourth, your code is open for SQL Injection, you must need to prevent with SQL Injection, you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

**Example:**

```
// ist param should be link identifier.
$Firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Firstname']);
```

Five, you are missing the `<form>` method, and method should be POST, because you are using `$_POST` in your code, something like

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="user.php">
```

**In last**, don't know, `$username = "username";` is the correct user of your database, i hope this is `root`.

**Suggestion for password:** you must need to learn about the secure password, just suggestion read this [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php).

**Side Note:** note that, `mysql_*` is deprecated and close in PHP 7.

Comment: This is the only answer that covered everything, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sudhar";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$Firstname=$_POST['Firstname'];
$Lastname=$_POST['Lastname'];
$Username=$_POST['Username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];




$sql="insert into useraccount(Firstname,Lastname,Username,email,Password)values('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Username','$Password','$email')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
echo "data inserted"
or die(mysqli_error());
}



?>
```

```css
html,body
{
margin:0px; 
height:100%;
}
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
  }
 .content
 {
width:100%;
height:400px;

 }

 .signup
 {
height:500px;

 }
  .footer
  {
    position:relative;
   background-color:black;
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
  <title>ASK</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boot.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>school name</h1>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="../project/photo/l.png"  height="150px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#mynavbar">schoolName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" target=_self>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="infra.html" target=_self>Infrastructure</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="stlogin.html">staff login</a></li>
            <li><a href="stdetails.html">staff details</a></li>
            <li><a href="class.html">class handling</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="signup.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="signup">
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="user.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fnmae" placeholder="Enter Firstname" name="Firstname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Lastname">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lnmae" placeholder="Enter Lastname" name="Lastname">
    </div></div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="Username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unmae" placeholder="Enter Username" name="Username">
    </div></div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div></div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="Password">
    </div></div>



    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button><br>
    
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer nav">
  <p> Copyrights@ &copy; WWW.schools.com</p>
  </div>   
  </body>
  </html>
```

please try this above code.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_post

You forgot type="text" and method="post". Check the link.

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML is wrong. Your `types` are not right. See the doc of HTML:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp.

And the ID's are not equal with the `POST` Params.

For example:

```
<input type="Lastname" class="form-control" id="lnmae" placeholder="Enter Lastname" name="Lastname">
```

Should be

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Lastname" placeholder="Enter Lastname" name="Lastname">
```